# Ignoring a model when using alembic autogenerate

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I am trying to autogenerate revisions for my DB using `alembic`. While doing so, I want to ignore some models (they have data types that are not supported by current version of MySQL). Here is what I tried and it seems to work fine, but I am not sure that's the most idiomatic way of doing it

inside `alembic/env.py`

```py
def include_object(object, type_, name, reflected, compare_to):
    if type_ == 'table' and name == 'model_to_be_ignored':
        return False
    return True
```

and then inside `run_migrations_online` and `run_migrations_offline` I gave `include_object=include_object` and this seems to be working fine.

Ideally I would like to use `skip_autogenerate=True`, but not sure I can define that, so that later on I can simply remove that line in the `models.py` and get my desired behavior when I upgrade to newer version of database.

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, `skip_autogenerate` is not automatically handled by Alembic nor SQLAlchemy. But you can add it to `Table.info` like this:

1. Define a mixin that adds `skip_autogenerate` to `Table.info`. This is based in Flask-SQLAlchemy's [BindMetaMixin](https://github.com/minisotm/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/master/flask_sqlalchemy/model.py#L114)

```
class ModelInfoMetaMixin(object):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, d):
        skip_autogenerate = d.pop("__skip_autogenerate__", None)

        super(ModelInfoMetaMixin, cls).__init__(name, bases, d)

        if skip_autogenerate is not None and getattr(cls, "__table__", None) is not None:
            cls.__table__.info["skip_autogenerate"] = skip_autogenerate
```

2. Use this mixin to define a meta class and pass it to `declarative_base()`

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeclarativeMeta, declarative_base

class DefaultMeta(ModelInfoMetaMixin, DeclarativeMeta):
    pass

Model = declarative_base(cls=BaseModel, metaclass=DefaultMeta)
```

3. Then you can define your models with this marker:

```
class OneModel(Model):
    __skip_autogenerate__ = True
    uuid = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)
```

4. Finally, `skip_autogenerate` will be available in Alembic's `include_object`:

```
def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    # skip objects marked with "skip_autogenerate"
    if object.info.get("skip_autogenerate", False):
        return False

    return True
```