# Alembic ignore specific tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm using alembic to manage database migrations as per user defined sqlalchemy models. My challenge is that ***I'd like for alembic to ignore any creation, deletion, or changes to a specific set of tables.***

**Note:** My Q is similar to this question [Ignoring a model when using alembic autogenerate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54978681/ignoring-a-model-when-using-alembic-autogenerate) but is different in that I want to control alembic from outside the model definition.

Here's a sample table I want to ignore:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base(metadata=MetaData())

class Ignore1(Base):
    """
    Signed in to the account...
    """
    __tablename__ = 'ignore_1'
    __table_args__ = {
        'info':{'skip_autogenerate':True}
        }
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String(20), nullable=True)
```

Example code (which does not solve my issue): 
**In `alembic/env.py`**

```py
# Ideally this is stored in my actual database, but for now, let's assume we have a list...
IGNORE_TABLES = ['ignore_1', 'ignore_2']

def include_object(object, name, type_, reflected, compare_to):
    """
    Should you include this table or not?
    """

    if type_ == 'table' and (name in IGNORE_TABLES or object.info.get("skip_autogenerate", False)):
        return False

    elif type_ == "column" and object.info.get("skip_autogenerate", False):
        return False

    return True

# Then add to config
context.configure(
    ...
    include_object=include_object,
    ...
    )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not solve my issue"? The filter `if type_ == 'table' and name in IGNORE_TABLES:` should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for diving into this @van --> the above code prevents creation of tables in `IGNORE_TABLES` but does not ignore creation of new columns.

Comment: OK, and how do you configure `skip_autogenerate` on your models? I am asking this question because the answer to another SO question you link to clearly states that the `skip_autogenerate` needs to be handled by you. Therefore, in order to understand **why** things do you work on your end, this information is missing.

Comment: I see. Let me add that to the Q... @van

Comment: I found a solution! @van

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*I found a solution to my problem!*

My error was in the instantiation of my `context` object in `env.py`

```
def run_migrations_offline():
    ...
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        include_object=include_object,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()
```

***I wasn't applying this change to context for online migrations:***

```
def run_migrations_online():
    ...
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection,
            target_metadata=target_metadata,
            # THE FOLLOWING LINE WAS MISSING FROM MY ORIGINAL CODE
            include_object=include_object, # <----------------------- THIS!
        )
    ...
```

Hopefully anyone else encountering this issue and experiencing similar turmoil can read through my question & following solution and recognize that despair is but a small dumb tweak from salvation.